# Nodejs API controller for switching between APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

Is there such thing as an API controller in Nodejs? An API layer that communicates with multiple APIs [that each return the same type of data, but completely different data models] and massaging the data to return to our client-side display? Is there a different term for this?

I have a simple CRUD application.

AngularJS front-end calls my RESTful Nodejs APIs on the back end.

Now, however, there is a 3rd party who has their own APIs and data that I would like my front-end to be able to use if the user wishes.

The data from the 3rd party API's is similar data to ours, but will not follow the same data model. I am trying to wrap my head around how I should begin to write an API the front-end will call that could go to either our API or the 3rd party [and possibly future 3rd parties] and massage the data so either way it is the same to the display.

Any resources or better ways to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a number of ways this could be accomplished with nodeJS.  How you set it up will be dependent on the details of your project, but here are a few ways to get that functionality:

1. Setup an endpoint that queries other endpoints.  For example, all api requests hit /api/1.0/:routing_params, and based off of that routing_param send out requests to various other apis. This data is returned to your backend which then sends the response to the browser.
2. Use something like expressJS to mount multiple routers, with each router handling the various endpoints for each api.  Documentation for express routing can be found here. [ExpressRouting](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)
3. Depending on your scaling/performance requirements you can also consider using something like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/#) to handle incoming requests and direct them to separate nodejs processes handling the various api logic.  This may be overkill, but is an easy way to keep things modular if you expect the need to run multiple nodejs processes and handle multiple future api endpoints.

That should provide some starting points, what you choose to do and how you implement it will be highly dependent on the specifications of your application.

Comment: Thanks. I like the sound of #1 but, What is the best way to store the config of all these 3rd party endoints? If my front end hits my new endpoint: '/api/1.0/:users' how to I know to map this to '/members' endpoint for 3rd party api A and '/users' endpoint for 3rd party api B, depending on who my client is configured to get data from? Will I need metadata for each of the 3rd party endpoints, so my backend will know how to format everything the same before sending the response?

Comment: There are many ways to store the data needed to correctly redirect your endpoints.  You could keep a config file in the root directory and require that file when you bootstrap your app.  You could also use require statements to modularize each request/response logic for the various endpoints.  There is no one right/wrong way to handle this, just ways that are better or worse for your particular use case.